# delete an exact numerical value from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

In asp.net, I have some values in a string as under:

> 1,12,123,21,23,256   and so on

I want that if i want to delete 1 then only 1 should be removed from the list, if I want to delete 12 then only number 12 should be removed from the list.

The code should be very less time taking since there will be a load of a lot of users on this button. Using string

*replace()* and *regex* , all occurances of 1 ans 12 got changed.

I tried the following:

```
string llist2 = "1,12,123,23,21";
string[] vals = llist2.Split(',');
int numtorem = 1;
vals = Array.FindAll(vals, val => val != numtorem).ToArray();
```

Here, vals is a string array so it wont work.
Then i tried `int[] vals = llist2.Split(',');` but *llist2* is a string, so it wont convert. If I add on more code for conversions, then code execution will be too much and page will become slow due to a lot of users working in parallel.

> NOTE: the string in the llist2 is coming from the database using a select query. I hope I will not be asked to share the select query code too.

Comment: 1) show your code - it's not clear what you have tried 2) provide examples of input and output strings - it's not clear how real string looks like and what to do with commas and whitespaces around numbers

Comment: Could you use a list of int instead? If so then you could use `list.Remove(value)` to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: "I have some values in a string" - yeah, but why? Have them in an appropriate structure (like a `List<int>`) so you can actually work with them. Don't work "[stringly typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped)".

Comment: The comma included list of numbers are coming from the database, they are stored in DB in a  varchar column. I need to remove a number from it when the user clicks on a button (Ajax is being used to avoid postback).

Comment: As @ Sergey Berezovskiy mentioned, give us sample input and sample output data, so we can understand what you need.

Comment: Now since codes have been added, can you people please remove your downvoting and answer the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't Worry Bro, people here are in habit of down voting the posts quickly rather than helping:
Here is the solution for you:

```
string llist2 = "1,12,123,23,21";
int[] vals = Array.ConvertAll(llist2.Split(','), int.Parse);
int numtorem = 1;
vals = Array.FindAll(vals, val => val != numtorem).ToArray();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, this worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's better to convert 1 number (the one to be removed), then the whole list.
update your code to convert the number to string and that's it

```
string llist2 = "1,12,123,23,21";
string[] vals = llist2.Split(',');
int numtorem = 1;
llist2 = String.Join(",", Array.FindAll(vals, val => val != numtorem.ToString()));
```

Comment: `Array.FindAll` returns an array. You don't need to create another one here. Also you can use `vals.Where(predicate)` instead of `Array.FindAll` to avoid any additional arrays creation

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Can you please post the relevant code according to your tip?

Answer (score 0):

You can split directly to `List<int>` and remove the number.

```
List<int> vals = llist2.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
vals.Remove(numtorem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
string llist2 = "1,12,123,23,21,1";
string[] vals = llist2.Split(',');
int numtorem = 1;
string[] results = Array.FindAll(vals, s => !s.Equals(Convert.ToString(numtorem))).ToArray();
```

Comment: You are converting things to strings rather than integers while exact whole number needs to be replaced?

Comment: updated my friend

Answer (score 0):

If yout don't want convert the list to integers, you can do the @ASh solution, or this:

```
string llist2 = "1,12,123,23,21";
int numtorem = 1;
llist2 = Regex.Replace(llist2, string.Format("^{0},|,{0}(,)|,{0}$", numtorem), "$1");

//"$1" is the first match group: (,) => string.Empty or ","
//Works fine with 1, 123, 21, etc...

//Console.WriteLine(llist2);
//Output 12,123,23,21
```

Comment: Edited for just simplifying.
The @ASh solution (that has disappeared) was to add a comma at the beginning and end of llist2 and replace the ("," + num + ",") to string.Empty, finally remove the added commas...